# barcode reader and printer issue

Tags: c#, barcode

I am wondering if anyone encountered the issue here:

I am sending a specific string to the printer, for example: `123456789`

It prints the barcode regarding that string, although I always need to play with the string otherwise the reader doesn't read exactly what I sent.

So I send: `123456789`

The reader reads: `0123456780`

Is there any way to send the data to the printer without having to change the format of the barcode?

Sending `123456789` to the printer, seeing that as a barcode, and then scanning that from the reader.

I'm kind of confused. Hope someone else has experienced the same issue and understands what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be alot easier if you knew the barcode format that's being printed/scanned. There are different types, most of which have a fixed format.

If you know this, you may either be able to configure either the reader or the printer, or at least you would know *why* and *how* to change the barcode format, rather than "having to play with it".

One possible scenario you may be experiencing is that a [UPC-A barcode can be stored as an EAN13 barcode](http://www.nationwidebarcode.com/are-upc-a-and-ean-13-the-same/); EAN13 contains 13 digits while UPC-A contains 12 - but that's just a guess for now.